# How to generate a filled PDF from Google sheets data from web form?

Tags: google-sheets, pdf-generation, reporting, spreadsheet, autofill

I've been asked to create an automated way to generate filled PDF reports from google sheet data that comes from a web form. I've been looking for places to start for a while and can't find anything helpful.

Is this something that Google can even do? Or would it have to be moved to another system like O365 or a custom app with something like filemaker? Are there any 3rd party apps that can take google sheet data and put it into a custom pdf?

I'm pretty new to this and am not really sure where to begin. Do you guys have any suggestions on what to read, places to go, or how to start? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create form: https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/

entered data will come into the spreadsheet...

use `FILTER` or `QUERY` to shift your incoming dataset as you need

export it like pdf:

[image]